# Preventing a web browser from opening during signout on iOS

Tags: javascript, react-native, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Im having trouble setting up authentication with the default Cognito Hosted UI for my mobile application.
I am working with Amplify in a react-native project.

Ive got sign in with Apple and google both configured in the backend.

When I signout instead of being immediately directed to the unauthenticated user page which is WelcomeScreen.js an intermediate safari browser is opening up that is just completely not needed.

I have deep linking configured in the AppDelegate and Url in info.plist file.

here is my code:

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Amplify,Storage, Auth, Hub} from 'aws-amplify';
import awsmobile from './src/aws-exports';
import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator';
import { ThemeProvider } from './ThemeContext';
import Toast from 'react-native-toast-message';
import WelcomeScreen from './WelcomeScreen';


Amplify.configure(awsmobile);
Storage.configure({
  customPrefix: {
    public: "",
  },
});

function App() {
  const [isUserLoggedIn, setIsUserLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    checkCurrentUser();

    const hubListener = Hub.listen('auth', ({ payload: { event } }) => {
      if (event === 'signIn' || event === 'cognitoHostedUI') {
        setIsUserLoggedIn(true);
      } else if (event === 'signOut') {
        setIsUserLoggedIn(false);
      }
    });

    return () => Hub.remove('auth', hubListener);
  }, []);

  const checkCurrentUser = async () => {
    try {
      await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      setIsUserLoggedIn(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('No current user', error);
      setIsUserLoggedIn(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {isUserLoggedIn ? (
          <AppNavigator />
        ) : (
          <WelcomeScreen />
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
      <Toast />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

WelcomeScreen.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Linking } from "react-native";
import { InAppBrowser } from 'react-native-inappbrowser-reborn'; // Import InAppBrowser
import awsmobile from './src/aws-exports';
import { Amplify} from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure(awsmobile);

const WelcomeScreen = () => {

  const signInWithHostedUI = async () => {
    const { domain, redirectSignIn, responseType, scope } = awsmobile.oauth;
    const url = `https://${domain}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=${responseType}&client_id=${awsmobile.aws_user_pools_web_client_id}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectSignIn)}&scope=${encodeURIComponent(scope.join(' '))}`;
  
    console.log("Attempting to open URL:", url); // Log the URL being opened
  
    try {
      const isAvailable = await InAppBrowser.isAvailable();
      console.log("InAppBrowser isAvailable:", isAvailable);
  
      if (isAvailable) {
        console.log("Opening In-App Browser for sign-in");
        await InAppBrowser.openAuth(url, redirectSignIn, {
          dismissButtonStyle: 'cancel',
          preferredBarTintColor: '#453AA4',
          preferredControlTintColor: 'white',
          readerMode: false,
          animated: true,
          modalEnabled: true,
          enableBarCollapsing: false,
          showTitle: false,
          enableUrlBarHiding: true,
          enableDefaultShare: false,
          enableUrlBarHiding:true,
          //ios property
          ephemeralWebSession: true,
        }).then((response) => {
          if (
            response.type === 'success' &&
            response.url
          ) {
            Linking.openURL(response.url);
            

          }
        });
      } else {
        Linking.openURL(url);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Linking.openURL(url);
    }

  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Welcome to Artiflect!</Text>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        Revolutionize the way you document and value your collections.
      </Text>

      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.loginButton}
          onPress={signInWithHostedUI}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Log In or Sign Up</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#76B947",
  },
  paragraph: {
    marginTop: 15,
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "white",
    marginHorizontal: 30,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 38,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "white",
    marginHorizontal: 30,
    marginTop: -20,
  },

  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 50,
  },
  loginButton: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#0B0B0B",
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 25,
    width: "40%",
  },
  signUpButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#0B0B0B",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#0B0B0B",
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 25,
    width: "40%",
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  // ... other styles as needed ...
});

export default WelcomeScreen;
```

Settings.js(location of the signout button)

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  Linking,
  Alert
} from "react-native";
import { Auth} from "aws-amplify";

import { ThemeContext } from "./ThemeContext";

export default function Settings({ navigation }) {
  const { theme, toggleTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  // State to track the current mode for immediate UI update
  const [currentMode, setCurrentMode] = useState(theme.mode);

  const [styles, setStyles] = useState(() => getStyles(theme));

  useEffect(() => {
    setStyles(getStyles(theme));
    setCurrentMode(theme.mode); // Update current mode when theme changes
  }, [theme]);

  const handleToggleTheme = () => {
    toggleTheme();
    setCurrentMode(currentMode === "light" ? "dark" : "light"); // Immediately update the mode for the button text
  };

  const openArtiflectLink = () => {
    Linking.openURL("https://artiflect.app");
  };

  const signOut = async () => {
    try {
      await Auth.signOut();
      // Handle any post-sign-out logic here, like redirecting to a sign-in screen
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error signing out:', error);
    }
  };

  const confirmSignOut = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Sign Out", // Title of the alert
      "Are you sure you want to sign out?", // Message shown to the user
      [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
          style: "cancel"
        },
        { text: "Yes", onPress: () => signOut() } // Call your signOut function here
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  };

  const navigateToContact = () => {
    navigation.navigate("contact");
  };

  const deleteAccount = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Delete Account",
      "Are you sure you want to permanently delete your account?",
      [
        // If the user confirms, proceed with account deletion
        {
          text: "Yes",
          onPress: async () => {
            try {
              const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
              user.deleteUser((err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                  console.error("Error deleting user account: ", err);
                  return;
                }
                console.log("Account deleted successfully", result);
                // Optionally, sign the user out and redirect them to a landing page
                signOut()
              });
            } catch (error) {
              console.error("Error fetching current user for deletion: ", error);
            }
          },
        },
        {
          text: "No",
          // If the user cancels, do nothing
          style: "cancel",
        },
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.buttonContainer}
        onPress={handleToggleTheme}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
          {currentMode === "dark" ? "Light Mode" : "Dark Mode"}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={confirmSignOut}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign Out</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.buttonContainer}
        onPress={navigateToContact}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Feedback</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.deletebuttonContainer}
      onPress={deleteAccount}
    >
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Delete Account</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.linkContainer}
        onPress={openArtiflectLink}
      >
        <Text style={styles.linkText}>Artiflect</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>AppName</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>AppName</string>
                <string>ios.AppName.app</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses your camera to capture images of trading cards for the purpose of identifying and providing information about the cards using AI.</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your microphone</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your photos</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>SplashScreen.storyboard</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
    <string>Light</string>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

AppDelegate.mm:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>



@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"Artiflect";
  self.initialProps = @{};

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  return [self getBundleURL];
}

- (NSURL *)getBundleURL
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@".expo/.virtual-metro-entry"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}
// Explicitly define remote notification delegates to ensure compatibility with some third-party libraries
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  [super application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  [super application:application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [super application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

@end
```

Comment: for some reason Im not receiving signIn event when using InAppBrowser's  openAuth